# `Dynamic` to a static class converter. Does it exist?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic, .net-4.0

I am using the `dynamic` type to read in a lot of JSON and process it.  Frankly, I'd rather have intellisense.  So I was wondering whether anyone has written a converter class that takes a `dynamic` object and generates a static class(es) out of it.

Comment: Can't you just convert the JSON to static anonymous types directly?

Comment: @BoltClock Not sure I follow you.

Comment: @KublaiKhan Oh, wow. The power. It's making me dizzy.  So is there some kind of special lounge for 10kers? Personal visit from Jeff?

Comment: @AngryHacker - Don't ask me, I just bus the tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [JSON C# Class Generator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/):

> This application generates C# classes from a sample JSON text, so you
>   can use strongly typed programming with JSON. It currently supports
>   typed arrays, typed objects, integers, floats, booleans, strings and
>   nullable types.

Comment: Thx, that is exactly what I was about to embark on writing.  Saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 3):

[JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356489.aspx) is ideal for this. It maps matching properties to a static type, and ignores those that don't.

You do need to give it the static type, but I think converting a dynamic to a anon static is a code smell.